# Switch throws Notice: Object of class User could not be converted to int

Tags: php, oop

I'm new to OOP and was trying to create a switch system where the variable sometimes returns a object and sometimes an constant (that links to an int, so it has better readability).

Here is some of the code

user.class.php

```
class User implements IUser {
    public static function initWithRegistration($mail, $username, $password) {
        if(!filter_var($mail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) return self::ERROR_REGISTER_INVALIDMAIL;
        // Loop through validation
        ...
        $instance = new self;
        // Set some vars to $instance
        ...
        return $instance;
    }
}
```

user.interface.php

```
interface IUser {
    ...
    // Register errors
    const ERROR_REGISTER_INVALIDMAIL = 7;
    // More validation constants && interface here
    ...
}
```

register.php

```
switch($user = User::initWithRegistration($mail, $username, $password)) {
            // Constant case's here
            ...
            case User::ERROR_REGISTER_INVALIDMAIL:
                $template->setError("Invalid mail.");
                break;

            default:
                $template->setError("Invalid error.");
                break;

            case true:
                // Do login here
                break;
        }
```

It just don't work, it even throws errors like `Notice: Object of class User could not be converted to int`.
I know that when initWithRegistration() returns a constant, the switch sees it as true. But I don't know any other way of working with errors.

I already tried to let initWithRegistration() return false when it doesn't pass the validation.
I even tried to create it without switches and constants (using if statements and let initWithRegistration() returns strings) but I think using switches and constants provide better readability.

How can I use a switch with constants where the variable is sometimes an int and sometimes an object?

Thank you

Comment: If you move that assignment above switch(), what happens?

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk Yeah, that works. But still throws `Notice: Object of class User could not be converted to int` and I want that PHP error reporting doesn't log error's without having to turn off error_reporting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to know whether `User::initWithRegistration(...)` is returning an instance of User or not, in which case you could either:

```
$user = User::initWithRegistration($mail, $username, $password);
switch(gettype($user)){
    case 'integer':
        // returned an integer, User not created
        break;
    case 'object':
        // returned an instance of User
}
```

Or, just to check if it returned an instance of User, you could simply:

```
$user = User::initWithRegistration($mail, $username, $password);
if($user instanceof User){
    // $user is a User object
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is - when you receive instance of `User`, system tries to compare a class to an int, and naturally, your typecasting fails.

What i'd recommend to do, is reworking your code with exceptions, like this:

```
class UserValidationException extends Exception {}

class User implements IUser {
    public static function initWithRegistration($mail, $username, $password) {
        if (!filter_var($mail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
             throw new UserValidationException();
        };
        // Loop through validation
        ...
        $instance = new self;
        // Set some vars to $instance
        ...
        return $instance;
    }
}
```

and in `register.php`

```
try {
    User::initWithRegistration($mail, $username, $password);
} catch (UserValidationException $e) {
    $template->setError("Invalid mail");
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $template->setError("Generic error");
}
```

This way you get more control over your error-reporting. Also, it is generally a bad idea to return inconsistent values from anywhere, as it is very error prone.

Comment: This is indeed a better way. But not exactly the answer to the question, so sorry for not accepting this. When using classes that extend Exception, should I create multiple classes like `class MailValidationException extends Exception {}` or just one `class UserValidationExecption extends Exception` with the functionality to report several errors?

Comment: Every exception can accept `message` and `code` parameters on construction, which could later be checked by `$e->getMessage()` and `$e->getCode()`. That way you can define one exception and handle it by error code.